# Сохранение файлов с одинаковыми именами: автоматическое увеличение счётчика в имени

Tags: python

Как сохранить одинаковые файлы? У меня есть много картинок на сервере, и зачастую они имеют одинаковое имя. Тоесть одинаковых имен может быть и 5, и 10... Как сделать так, чтобы при их скачивании и сохранении, скрипт автоматически давал им в конец, допустим, цифру 1,2,3 и тд? Чтобы было photo(1).jpg, photo(2).jpg и тд. 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, что мешает вам это сделать, покажите код вашего скрипта что ли

Comment: Мне ничего не мешает, я просто не понимаю как это сделать. Там простейшая функция загрузки фото(requests.get(URL) with open(), file.write и т.д.)

Comment: Что мешает увеличивать счетчик и на его основании формировать имена?

Comment: Покажите свою функцию, чтобы был предметный разговор.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43167607/5741205

Comment: @True_prog Собственно ничего не должно мешать подставить внутрь `with open(...)`  нужную вам строку, созданию строк учат в любом учебнике, непонятно в чём проблема

Answer (score 2):

Увеличиваем счётчик до тех пор пока несуществующее имя файла не будет найдено:

```
import itertools
from pathlib import Path

def new_filename(filename):
    path = Path(filename)
    if not path.exists():
        return path
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        new_path = path.parent / (path.stem + f'({i})' + path.suffix)
        if not new_path.exists():
            return new_path
```

Пример:

```
>>> new_filename('photo.jpg') 
PosixPath('photo(2).jpg')  # assuming photo.jpg, photo(1).jpg exist already
```